# How to parse Terraform with sensitive variables

Tags: terraform, hcl

We are using `gohcl.DecodeBody` to parse Terraform scripts such as [this one](https://github.com/terraform-ibm-modules/terraform-ibm-toolkit-resource-group/blob/main/variables.tf#L4) that marks variables as `sensitive`. We are not passing in an `EvalContext`:

```
diags := gohcl.DecodeBody(file.Body, nil, &root)
```

However this results in a diagnostic error:

```
2022/12/01 10:40:51 - .envbuilderTmpDir/github.com/terraform-ibm-modules/terraform-ibm-toolkit-resource-group/variables.tf:4,3-12: Unsupported argument; An argument named "sensitive" is not expected here.
```

As I read the docs, I think we need to pass in an `EvalContext` so the decoder can handle the sensitive attribute, but I'm not sure how to construct it. We don't really care about the sensitive attribute; we'd be fine if we could tell the decoder to ignore it. I've tried passing an empty one but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is reporting that the given schema does not declare an argument named `sensitive`.

When you are using the `gohcl` abstraction to decode HCL the schema is inferred automatically using reflection against the type of the value you passed in to the last argument. That means that the schema will be decided based on whatever type you've declared for your variable `root`, which you didn't show in your question.

To make your program accept an argument called `sensitive` inside variable blocks, you will need to identify which struct type in your program is representing `variable` blocks and add an extra field to it which is tagged to represent that it represents an argument called `sensitive`:

```
type VariableBlock struct {
    // ...
    Sensitive hcl.Expression `hcl:"sensitive"`
}
```

I chose the target type `hcl.Expression` here because you mentioned in your question that you don't plan to actually make use of the `sensitive` argument value. Decoding into `hcl.Expression` means that `gohcl` will just capture directly whatever expression was assigned to `sensitive` without performing any further type checking or type conversion.

If you did want to make use of the `sensitive` value in your program then you might prefer to decode into a Go `bool` field instead, which would then cause `gohcl` to require that the given value be a HCL boolean value and will convert it into a Go `bool` value to assign into the result.

Note that Terraform itself doesn't use the `gohcl` package, so you won't be able to implement all aspects of the Terraform language through that abstraction. Depending on your goals, you may find it better to use the higher-level library [terraform-config-inspect](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect), which encapsulates the HCL-related details of the Terraform language and exposes only a subset of the language at a higher level of abstraction that's more appropriate for building certain kinds of tools for working with Terraform modules.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot I needed to add that to our `struct`. Works now. I do think using `terraform-config-inspect` is the better approach though. Thanks for the reference.